# Update files created by generator in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator

I have a generator that creates some view files.

I'm wondering about the extensibility of the generator - if there is a change in the generator template file, do I need to modify the existing files which were created by the generator manually?

I know that I can overwrite the existing files by running the generator command. But if I have edited the file after the file generation, overwriting can remove some necessary parts.

What is the best method to apply the latest generator template in the existing file?

Comment: I would copy the old file, run the generator, and the compare the diff. I don't think generators will update a file generally. Maybe some specific ones would do that if the creator implemented that logic, but you would need to verify that in the readme of the gem that provides that generator.

Comment: Updating existing files is generally avoided (exept by tossing in a oneliner macro call) since its very error prone and is left to the users. Ruby isn't a structured language like for example Lisp where the whole program can be manipulated as data. You should consider if the file needs to be updated regularily then maybe it should be a part of the lib and not generated and if it can be solved by providing a better API from the lib.

Answer (score 0):

Run the generator and then use git to determine which parts of the change to the generated views you want to keep.

You can do this through the command line using `git add -p` to stage certain parts of files before you commit (From [Git Tools - Interactive Staging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging)).

Any decent git GUI would also allow you to stage changes in this way too.